# Determine which fonts have been blacklisted by fontconfig?

Tags: fonts, fontconfig

Is there anything like the opposite of [`fc-list`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/fc-list), which will list font files which were explicitly blacklisted/rejected by fontconfig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, and I don't think there will be unless something re-implements the entire parsing logic of fontconfig. When you blacklist a font, applications (including `fc-list`) simply don't see them.

If you [check the source](https://github.com/behdad/fontconfig/blob/master/src/fccfg.c#L2401), there is no logging, no (extra) debugging and no hooks.

That said, it's a simple patch to fontconfig to log the matching and rejection:

```
--- src/fccfg.c.orig    2018-10-04 18:55:53.000000000 +0100
+++ src/fccfg.c 2018-10-04 19:15:46.000000000 +0100
@@ -2349,9 +2349,16 @@
 {
     int i;

-    for (i = 0; i < patterns->nfont; i++)
-   if (FcListPatternMatchAny (patterns->fonts[i], font))
-       return FcTrue;
+    printf("!check for <%s>:\n",
+        FcPatternFormat((FcPattern *)font,(FcChar8 *)"%{file}"));
+    for (i = 0; i < patterns->nfont; i++) {
+        FcPatternPrint(patterns->fonts[i]);
+       if (FcListPatternMatchAny (patterns->fonts[i], font)) {
+            printf("!pattern match %i of %i\n",i,patterns->nfont);
+           return FcTrue;
+        }
+    }
+    if (patterns->nfont) printf("!pattern does not match\n");
     return FcFalse;
 }

@@ -2359,10 +2366,19 @@
 FcConfigAcceptFont (FcConfig           *config,
                const FcPattern *font)
 {
-    if (FcConfigPatternsMatch (config->acceptPatterns, font))
-   return FcTrue;
-    if (FcConfigPatternsMatch (config->rejectPatterns, font))
-   return FcFalse;
+    if (FcConfigPatternsMatch (config->acceptPatterns, font)) {
+        printf("!accepting file by pattern: ");
+        printf("%s\n",FcPatternFormat((FcPattern *)font,(FcChar8 *)"%{file}"));
+       return FcTrue;
+    }
+    if (FcConfigPatternsMatch (config->rejectPatterns, font)) {
+        printf("!rejecting file by pattern: ");
+        printf("%s\n",FcPatternFormat((FcPattern *)font,(FcChar8 *)"%{file}"));
+       return FcFalse;
+    }
+    printf("!default accept: %s\n",
+        FcPatternFormat((FcPattern *)font,(FcChar8 *)"%{file}"));
+    
     return FcTrue;
 }
```

The above applies cleanly to fontconfig-2.11.95, which is the most recent source I had lying around. `FC_DEBUG` prints to stderr, the above prints to stdout to avoid interleaving output issues (`FcPatternPrint()` prints to stdout).

That code resides in `libfontconfig.so`, you can test the results with something like:

```
LD_PRELOAD=src/.libs/libfontconfig.so.1.9.1 fc-list
```

and assuming you have [anything interesting in your config](https://github.com/behdad/fontconfig/blob/master/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf) you should see the results.

Answer (score 2):

`fontconfig` has debugging traces which can be enabled with an environment variable.  This is probably lower-level than you would like (no nice reports), but the information is there.

The feature is described in [Debugging Applications](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html), in the user manual:

> To help diagnose font and applications problems, fontconfig is built with a large amount of internal debugging left enabled. It is controlled by means of the **`FC_DEBUG`** environment variable. The value of this variable is interpreted as a number, and each bit within that value controls different debugging messages.

Further reading:

- [I stared into the fontconfig, and the fontconfig stared back at me](https://eev.ee/blog/2015/05/20/i-stared-into-the-fontconfig-and-the-fontconfig-stared-back-at-me/)  (2015)
- [[Fontconfig] Environment var to set font trace debug output?](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/fontconfig/2003-April/000223.html) (2003)

Comment: That didn't help, but it's something I'll keep in mind for future font issues.